# extracting items from json with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

I made an api query which returns a json as response. I am trying to extract the temperature_2m for the first time in the list (2022-11-03T00:00) which is 5.7, not sure how to get it with python

```
api_query ={
    "latitude": 52.52,
    "longitude": 13.419998,
    "generationtime_ms": 0.36203861236572266,
    "utc_offset_seconds": 0,
    "timezone": "GMT",
    "timezone_abbreviation": "GMT",
    "elevation": 38.0,
    "hourly_units": {
        "time": "iso8601",
        "temperature_2m": "°C"
    },
    "hourly": {
        "time": [
            "2022-11-03T00:00",
            "2022-11-03T01:00"
           
        ],
        "temperature_2m": [
            5.7,
            5.2
           
        ]
    }
}

for key in api_query:
    temperature = api_query['hourly']['time'][0]['temperature_2m']
    print(temperature)
```

Comment: temperature = api_query['hourly']['temperature_2m'][0]
and 
time = api_query['hourly']['time'][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working:

```
temperature = api_query['hourly']['time'][0]['temperature_2m']
```

coz temperature is a sub attribute from "hourly" but not from "time"

you need instead:

for the temp:

```
temperature = api_query['hourly']['temperature_2m'][0]
print(temperature)
```

and for the time:

```
time = api_query['hourly']['time'][0]
```

here a Jupyter Notebook
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`temperature = api_query['hourly']['temperature_2m'][0]`